# Unable to post message to Azure Service Bus Queue from Azure API using Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-api-management, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to test out the sample code by azure "**Authenticate using Managed Identity to access Service Bus**" and its on github:

[Azure API Management Policy Snippets](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Authenticate%20using%20Managed%20Identity%20to%20access%20Service%20Bus.xml)

What I have done is in below steps:

1. Created an Azure API Management Service. In this I added an API which has a POST method
2. I also enabled a System Generated Managed Identity for this APIM
3. I created a Service Bus and create a queue
4. I added the managed identity to a role of "Azure Service Bus Data Sender" on the queue.
5. Last, I modified the code from azure to have names from objects I created above and it looks like below:

[image]

On running a test on API I get error: "500 Internal Server Error". The message of course is not being sent. Any idea what I may be doing wrong here? Help appreciated.

Comment: Have you check api management logs ? Could you share with us please.

Comment: Also I dont think you need you need to specify the api-version when setting the backend service url. This api-version seems out dated.

Comment: You probably also have to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be issue with your Authorization header and the calling URL. All other steps looks good.

Please find below Policy code snippet which works fine at my end. I am able to send the data to service bus successfully. My operation endpoint is '/messages' with POST method.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue which is almost what @pankaj has suggested.
I made a mistake when I created a POST operation on the api I created. When we add an operation for an api in azure apim, it asks for a URL also as shown below:
[![Azure API - adding an Operation][1]

The issue was that I added a random text something like "/message".
What this does is, it adds this path to the **set-backend-service base-url**

As that modified backend url was incorrect, so was the reason for error. I updated it to just a "/" in the POST operation path and the error got resolved.

I then again faced this issue when my request had some query parameters. It was again appending these query parameters to the backend url. To resolve that I added below:

```
<set-query-parameter name="{{replace-with-query-param}}" exists-action="delete" />
```

Thank you everyone for trying to help me. Hopefully, this post will be of some help to others
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rechc.jpg